# Is this function continous and differentiable on $(0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, continuity

Consider $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined as:
$$f(x,y)=\cases {x^{\frac{4}{3}}\sin\frac{y}{x}\quad x\neq0
\\0\qquad\hspace{9.5mm} x=0 
}$$

It is clear that $f$ is continous at $(0,0)$, as for differentiation it gets a bit more tedious. First compute the partial derivative on $x$:
$$\partial_x f(x,y)=\cases{\frac{4}{3}x^{\frac{1}{3}}\sin\frac{y}{x}-x^{-\frac{2}{3}}\cos\frac{y}{x}\qquad x\neq0\\0\qquad\hspace{41.5mm}x=0}$$
which turns out not continous at $(0,0)$: if I'm not mistaken the limit should diverge. But the partial derivative in $y$ turns out to be continous so now I'm not sure at which points the function does not admit differentiation. I don't remember all the hypothesis but I know that the differential does exist also when at most only one of the partial derivatives is not continous. Can we say $f$ admits differential on the whole domain or does the discontinuity of $\partial_x f$  ensure $(0,y)$ is family of points of non-differentiability?